# LiteSpeed Settings - Shared Hosting

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

I put my site on a Shared Hosting which uses Litespeed.

I know that it is possible to override the Connection Timeouts set on the Litespeed Server, locally in the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule Litespeed>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
</IfModule>
```

I need to override the following directive: Max Request Body Size. Is it possible to override it inside .htaccess or only on the server?

Reason is I need to upload files bigger than 500 MB and it seems that this is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately to change Max Request Body Size requires a Server Level change. There is currently no .htaccess rule to override it at this time.

You might want to contact your Shared Hosting Provider to see if they can increase the limit for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer!! the shared hosting provider says its not possible to set it per peer and they don't want to change it globally.